# HTML highlighting within javascript strings doesnt work right on Intellij Idea

Tags: javascript, html, express, intellij-idea

I am writing html within javascript in my express server (intellij IDEA ultimate), and when i press option + up to select the outter tag in html, it most of the times get the wrong one.

Hard to explain so here is a before and after. I highlight body, i expect pressing option + up to highlight the rest of the body, but instead it goes wild.

is this a bug? is there a fix for this?

Before pressing option + up:
[image]

After pressing option + up:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact a bug. [Opened an issue on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-65478/Javascript-template-strings-in-HTML-break-Extend-Selection).

Closing

Answer (score 0):

I see that you created an issue on YouTrack: [WEB-65478](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-65478/Javascript-template-strings-in-HTML-break-Extend-Selection). Thank you for that.

Comment: Would love to have this sorted out asap and the team seems responsive. let's hope it gets resolved soon